# What solution do I need to use in this question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometry

Question:

Jojo and Albert left the same point and hike in different directions. their displacements are $\Delta x= 4$ km and $\Delta y= 6$ km.

How far are they from each other?

Comment: Have you drawn a picture?

Comment: What have solutions have you tried?

Comment: What is the angle between Jojo's and Albert's  different walking directions?

Answer (score 4):

The distance between two points in a coordinate plane is: $d=\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2 }.$ This comes from the pythagorean Theorem.

Comment: Why did I get a negative vote?

Comment: In order to discourage homework-like questions that show no effort, it's best to leave them unanswered I think

Comment: That's why there are tags. If you don't want to answer or read questions tagged with "homework-and-exercises" you can filter it. I'm giving her a big clue of how to answer her question.

Comment: I disagree.  Leaving them unanswered is just kind of rude.  At least close the question and explain why.

Comment: @Sean, if the answerer wants to answer homework and the answer is correct, dont see a reason for (negative) downvote (note that many people here actually got high rep by answering homeworks, before this "policy" change)

Comment: @Nick - I think that eventually will happen if the OP doesn't edit the question to include his/her effort towards solution. This isn't about a policy towards a particular guy or answer, but that the community finds it a tad distasteful. e.g. see [this recent meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6245/sanction-for-answering-a-homework-question). But again, it is difficult to clearly draw a line.

Comment: @VladimirVargas - I haven't downvoted, nor I will, because this answer doesn't deserve a downvote. But I think the downvotes are coming because having an upvoted answer prevents this Q (which has no research effort) from being closed. People probably don't want that.

Comment: @New_new_newbie I didn't know that having an upvoted answer prevented a question from being closed. However, if the answer has 0 votes I don't see the point in downvoting when the answer is correct.

Comment: To be clear, I wasn't the one that down voted and I'm fairly new around here. However, several meta posts (can't link to them- I'm on my phone) appear to REALLY discourage answering bad homework problems. It's not good enough to just down vote and wait until it's closed because it might take hours to close, in which case someone has already answered it.

Comment: I downvoted the question. But it was easy to answer it so I did it.

Comment: @VladimirVargas, well seeing this comment of yours, makes me think of the worse kind of elitism and crawling. First you downvoted the question (because it is really silly and not up to us), and then youy answered the (silly) question (you downvoted), because *it was easy* (and you just need the upvotes)

Comment: @VladimirVargas,  actually i flaged this post as *vote hunting of the worst kind* (and this is despite my other comment here about anwering homework questions)

Comment: @NikosM. I'm sorry for my bad use of English. In my native language, Spanish, we have two words that are translated vaguely to "simple" and "easy", which are 'sencillo' and 'fácil'. 'Fácil' is raw easy. 'Sencillo' means with no complexity, something is 'sencillo' when it causes you no trouble to execute. What I was trying to say when I wrote "it was easy to answer it" is that the was quite straightforward and evident to me. (continues in the next comment)

Comment: I'm starting studying physics and was recommended by a friend this website. I answer questions because I can review what I have studied and because I find it pleasant to help other people with their questions and to share knowledge. I'm quite busy studying, however I always try to come to this site to ask what I don't understand from what I'm studying, and to answer things that I've already studied. It would be a very sad situation if someone comes here to get votes and points. (continues in the next comment)

Comment: When someone downvotes an answer it is because it is not useful to answer the question, and I don't see the point of trying to discourage these kind of questions by downvoting the answers.

I have found plenty of questions googling them, and I think that the greatest value of these communities is not to answer the question **to** the person who asked the question, but rather **to all** the people who find the question and find it an its answer very useful. This is why I do not agree with "not answering" homework questions, because all questions are useful to somebody.

Comment: @VladimirVargas, ok thank you for your explanation, still downvoting the question and then posting an answer either because it is simple or easy, does not sound good. In fact personaly i encourage answering homeworks provided an elucidation is given to further understanding and knowledge (regardless if easy or complex).

Comment: @VladimirVargas not every _useful_ question is appropriate on this site. We've decided not to allow no-effort homework questions like this one, in an effort to maintain the quality of questions at a certain level, and answering such questions does undermine our effort just a tiny bit. If you don't agree with not answering these no-effort questions, you're certainly allowed to believe that, but we'd _prefer_ you not do so here on this site. If it's really important to you to answer those kinds of questions, there are other sites where you can do that.

Comment: @DavidZ I won't answer any other questions  with no effort.

Comment: @VladimirVargas thanks, the community appreciates it. Though let me clarify that this is not something you would get in trouble for (unless you are doing it consistently, frequently, and with a clear intent to disrupt the site). If you do answer a no-effort homework question, your answer might get deleted but it doesn't count against you.